Why do I have 2 bash processes when I openede only one terminal session?
I am using windows WSL2, and opened just one terminal session. I used the command ps and ps a. From what I know, the bash with PID 559 is the shell I am interacting with. The question is, why do I have another bash with PID 399? I have literally just one terminal opened. No other sessions are alive.
Below is the CLI response.
mike@DESKTOP-3B9ANKQ:~$ ps a
    PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    187 hvc0     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear --keep-baud - 115200,38400,9600 vt220
    205 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear - linux
    317 pts/1    Ss     0:00 /bin/login -f
    399 pts/1    S+     0:00 -bash
    559 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
    591 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps a
mike@DESKTOP-3B9ANKQ:~$ ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
    559 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
    592 pts/0    00:00:00 ps

running pstree gives
systemd─┬─2*[agetty]
        ├─cron
        ├─dbus-daemon
        ├─init-systemd(Ub─┬─SessionLeader───Relay(388)───bash───pstree
        │                 ├─init───{init}
        │                 ├─login───bash
        │                 └─{init-systemd(Ub}
        ├─polkitd───3*[{polkitd}]
        ├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
        ├─systemd───(sd-pam)
        ├─systemd-journal
        ├─systemd-logind
        ├─systemd-resolve
        ├─systemd-timesyn───{systemd-timesyn}
        ├─systemd-udevd
        ├─unattended-upgr───{unattended-upgr}
        └─wsl-pro-service───7*[{wsl-pro-service}]```


Can you try running pstree to see how the processes are related?

@choroba I updated the question after running pstree

I think running pstree -pa might be more useful, since we will have PIDs to match (when posting the output of that, please update the output of ps and ps a so we have consistent PIDs)
